# Firebase Cloud Functions: security

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need an answer from Firebase team members:
If I create cloud functions which will be used to provide my cryptocurrency exchange service 
**- is it really secure**?
I mean MITM attacks, DDoS, etc.
This question is **only about** functions content(no one can get access to read it or sniffer transfered data) security, NOT about functions logic.
And no one can DDoS cloud functions endpoints to make them unavailable to users??
For 1st phase I want to create Android app, which will be like cryptocurrency wallet with exchange functions. I have to be sure hackers is not available to, for example, decompile/disassemble .apk file and hack it to sniff the data transfering from device to Firebase.
Is it really possible?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a discussion.  Please use a forum such as firebase-talk instead of Stack Overflow.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data is protected if correct protection methods are followed
by The cors npm package

You can view this topic for more details

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/time-server